# Unresolved ruby reference in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

Is there any way to avoid the "unresolved ruby reference" warning in RubyMine IDE?
for example, when some code in my view calls a method of the view helper, I get the "unresolved ruby reference" warning even though the code works.

The case described above is just one of many.
Another example is when using RSpec:

```
  it "should require an email" do
    no_email_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:email => ""))
    no_email_user.should_not be_valid
  end
```

the parameter "be_valid" is not known to the RubyMine IDE.

My question is - is there any way to solve this? should I require additional files? should I do something differently?
Those false positives regarding unresolved ruby methods/constants are really disturbing, and it also affects the results of the "find usages" action in RubyMine.

I'm using RubyMine 3.1
I would really appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

Comment: I just installed RubyMine 3.1 for Linux with a Windowsish click->click->Finish style, started it (repaired Java, as told), created a new empty project, and it looks like Inspection is not working at all. I had once a simple "puts 'hello Worlds'" that triggered a "Unresolved Ruby reference". Next, I created a new method (this didn't triggered the error) but when I wanted to invoke it, the invoking method name triggered the error. Otherwise the scripts run OK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue is [already submitted](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-3965) to the RubyMine bug tracker, please watch/vote.

Comment: ... and still no solution.

Comment: Hey, it's 2017, and guess what? `Cannot find your stuff that still works...`

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case this is hard to solve. Ruby allows great magic to happen using `method_missing` and as far as i know, the `be_valid` is also implemented in this way. Actually there is no `be_valid` but it calls the `valid?` method and expects it to be true.

In rspec, this work for any method ending in a `?`. So if you have a method `ready?`, you can write `should be_ready`.

I am a fulltime Rubymine user, but i do not know how they could solve that nor do i expect it.

Comment: OK, I understand, thanks.
but what about the methods in view helpers that are regarded as unresolved reference from the view?

Comment: Ah, that i think is a bug in Rubymine 3.1.1. This seemed to work in the previous version, and you can find it in their bug tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-7983, which is linked to http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-7684. So i guess it will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

To turn off the warning you are getting in RubyMine 3.1, which I think might be your original question, you need to go to File->Preferences.  Then, on the left, go to "Inspections".  Open up the "Ruby" section and uncheck "Unresolved Ruby Reference."  The Preferences is searchable so, if you get others like that, you might try the search.  Good luck!

Comment: I don't want to turn off the warning, because the real problem is not the warning, but the fact that the method call does not count as a reference for RubyMine (for example - it does not take this method call into account when I refactor/rename the original mehtod...